# Why does $q \equiv (r-1)/2 \mod r$ mean that $2q \equiv -1 \mod r$?

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

In the paper [Safe Prime Generation with a Combined Sieve](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.80.4540&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Michael J. Wiener, the author states:

> For any small odd prime $r$, we can eliminate candidates for $q$ that are congruent to $(r − 1)/2\mod r$ because they lead to $p$ being divisible by $r$.

(where $p = 2q + 1$)

But he did not explain why for the uninitiated.  As such I would like to know why $(p-1)/2 \equiv (r-1)/2 \mod r$ means that $p \equiv 0 \mod r$.

Or to put it another way, why does $q \equiv (r-1)/2 \mod r$ mean that $2q \equiv -1 \mod r$?

Comment: Multiply by $2$.

Comment: @user6312: Oh, now I feel dumb.  Thanks!  But I can't mark a comment as an answer.

Comment: That's OK, I knew that quickly enough would come an answer that you could accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just expand:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
q&\equiv&(r-1)/2\mod r\\
2q&\equiv&r-1\mod r\\
2q&\equiv&-1\mod r
\end{eqnarray}$$